# Learning Core Data for iOS Development

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios4, xcode4

I have been trying to learn iPhone development for a while now. I am now interested in looking at building a iPhone app using *Core Data*. I built a app using sql lite. The app I created using sql lite basically asks the user for two fields of information "firstname" and "lastname" and then it goes into a UI Table View. The user can then select their name in that list and then it goes to a new view with a label with there name. Really basic app. Im just trying to grasp the ideas on how to make a iOS app.

Any Suggestions on what tutorials I could use to learn core data and then display that information in a new view?

Answer (score 2):

Good you decided to learn core data, a powerful alternative to sqlite.. See [this](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started) Ray Wenderlich tutorial to get first grasp of core data. Then read a descriptive tutorial about core data [here](http://www.bukisa.com/articles/180100_iphone-core-data-tutorial-part-1)..To cap it off, you should read [this](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/02/differences-between-core-data-and.html)..

Answer (score 1):

Core Data is a great technology, and I use it, but beware that it's pretty complicated so don't get discouraged...  An alternative and additional tool you may want to investigate is [NSUserDefaults](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) which fills a gap between CD and SQL imho. (Persistent dictionary, basically)

This answer is more of a comment but I can't link as nicely there

Comment: NSUserDefault is useful for storage of simple data structures..For storing large data structures core data or sqlite is better..I agree that coredata is complicated initially, but it is an effort worth taking..

Answer (score 0):

For `core Data` I suggest you to refer [HeadFirst iPhoneDevelopment](http://www.headfirstlabs.com/books/hfiphonedev/) Chapter 8.
I think it helps you.